# How can I overwrite the TensorBoard graphics when overwriting the log directory, instead of overlaying both graphics?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I'm implementing a function to predict how accuracy will evolve when training a model. It is intended to read the log files written by TensorBoard when training a model, compute the predictions for the future epochs and write them into the log files again for them to be shown on the board. At each epoch, new predictions are made, so I would like to remove the predictions plots made on the previous epochs.

Right now, I just overwrite the log file to delete from it the last predictions and write the new ones. But apparently, TensorBoard doesn't remove the plots from the deleted directory, it just overlays the new plots. After some epochs, the graphic is a complete mess and it's very difficult to distinguish the current prediction from the past ones, which we don't care about anymore.

I am working on Colab, and I launch TensorBoard like this:

```
%reload_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir tb_dir
```

I even tried reloading it, or executing the cell again after the model ends training, but it still shows the deleted log content. I guess that it is saved internally somewhere. I would need some function to remove that, and to do it while the model is training instead of having to relaunch TensorBoard somehow, as that would involve having to wait until the end of the training in order to see the good graphics. This is the skeleton of my code:

```
for i in range(total_epochs):
    tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
    model.fit(
        x_train, y_train,
        batch_size = 32,
        epochs = 1,
        verbose = 1,
        validation_data = validation_data,
        callbacks=[tb_callback]
    )
    event_dict = read_events(log_dir)
    predictions = predict(event_dict)
    write_events(tb_dir, event_dict, predictions)
```

Where the last 3 functions are implemented by me. I used a different directory for the logs that are written while the model trains and for the ones that TB reads to make sure it's not messing with that, but still no success. `write_events` deletes all content of the directory before writing it again. I have tested them so I'm sure that the content is being written and overwritten correctly so that previous data is being deleted.

I would need something to put on that loop to maybe flush all plots in TB so that it only shows the current content of the logs. Or maybe there's an option when launching TB so that it automatically does that constantly. Is there such a thing?